# Как расположить центр карты leaflet-react согласно геолокации пользователя и определить ее границы?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leafletjs

Всем привет! Моя задача - загрузить карту, центр карты необходимо расположить по местонахождению пользователя. Также необходимо получить границы этой карты. При использовании следующего кода получаю ошибку: „TypeError: Cannot read property 'locate' of undefined (anonymous function)”.
Всем большое спасибо за любую помощь!

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import restaurantsInfo from "./RestaurantsList.json";
import "./App.css";
import { MapContainer, Marker, Popup, TileLayer, useMapEvents } from "react-leaflet";
import { Icon, latLng } from "leaflet";
import Restaurants from "./Restaurants.js";
import LocationMarker from "./LocationMarker.js";
import L from 'leaflet';

const myLocation = [49.1951, 16.6068];
const defaultZoom = 13;

export default function App() {

  const mapRef = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    const { current = {} } = mapRef;
    const { leafletElement: map } = current;
    map.locate({
    setView: true,
    });
    map.on('locationfound', handleOnLocationFound);
  }, []);

  function handleOnLocationFound(event) {
    const { current = {} } = mapRef;
    const { leafletElement: map } = current;
    const latlng = event.latlng;
    const radius = event.accuracy;
    const circle = L.circle(latlng, radius);
    circle.addTo(map);
  }

  return (
    <div class="container">
    <div style={{height: '400px', width: '500px'}} class="map">
    
    <MapContainer ref={mapRef} center={myLocation} zoom={defaultZoom} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
    <TileLayer
      attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
    />
< /MapContainer >
```